# Testing an MVC application by returning a basic debug ViewResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm somewhat experienced with C# but am totally new to MVC4 and am struggling with someonething simple. I am trying to make some edits in an existing application, starting with the controller, and I want to make sure an action is running correctly by making a basic test.

I would like to have an action in the controller return a ViewResult that has some basic content in it that I can fiddle with (just a "Hello World" or something similar), just to make sure that the action is returning a ViewResult correctly before I start giving it more complex functionality.

Currently the action in my controller looks like:

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var v = new ViewResult();
        v.ViewData["Message"] = "HELLO THERE";
        return v;
    }
```

Obviously you can see I'm struggling with basics. I've looked at some tutorials, but those seem to focus on how to create a View in the context of making a new View *project* in Visual Studio, which isn't what I want. I would like to just drop some basic content into a view object in the action, so I can test whether I'm properly calling the action or not, rather than making an actual file containing view data.

Any insight is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something without the view, you can't return an `ActionResult` which loads a view (in your case, one named named 'Test' as you do not specify).

You could create a void controller (I think at least - I have never done it) - but why not create a simple view that just prints you message:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "HELLO THERE";
    return View("DebugView");
}
```

And then DebugView.cshtml is just:

```
@ViewData["Message"]
```

Tested the above and works. As someone else pointed out, you could return other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it ...just create an empty view with same name as the action and you are done

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {

        ViewData["Message"] = "HELLO THERE";
        return view();
    }
```

Create the Test view with nothing in it

Answer (score 1):

By convention, you're meant to have a view file which is returned from each controller action.    If you want to play around with a debug view, just create a temporary view file and pass the string to the view.  You can return other data types like Json, to just return data (minus a view) though, try this.

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
    return Content("hello world!");
}
```

Whilst we're on the subject, it might be better if you wrote unit tests around your controller.  Ideally, your data shouldn't be modified by the view and should just have basic view logic and display your view model.  A unit test would allow you to see what is being returned by a controller's action rather than having to create a debug view or touch anything View related.

Answer (score 0):

you can return any thing by mvc not only action result

```
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }
```